# 2 dimensional array - pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've declared 3 2 dimensional arrays in class Zadanie and in one position in the program I want to print the value for all the objects. Unfortunately it turns out, that they point at the same place in the memory and, as a result, they print 20 times the value for 1st object.

(...)

```
class Zadanie
{
  int dlugosc;
  int **operacja1;
  int **operacja2;
  int **operacja3;
  public:
      Zadanie(int **t1, int **t2, int **t3){
        operacja1= new int*[1];
        operacja1[0]=new int[2];
        operacja2= new int*[1];
        operacja2[0]=new int[2];
        operacja3= new int*[1];
        operacja3[0]=new int[2];
        operacja1=t1;
        operacja2=t2;
        operacja3=t3;
        dlugosc=operacja1[0][1]+operacja2[0][1]+operacja3[0][1];
    }

};
```

(...)

```
srand( time(NULL));
    int maszyna[3];
    int czas[3];
    vector <Zadanie> zadania;
    int **t1;
    t1= new int*[1];
    t1[0]=new int[2];

    int **t2;
    t2= new int*[1];
    t2[0]=new int[2];

    int **t3;
    t3= new int*[1];
    t3[0]=new int[2];

    for (int s=0; s<20; s++ )
    {
        for (int w=0; w<3; w++)
        {
            czas[w]=(rand() % 20) +1;
            maszyna[w]= (rand() % 3) +1;
            if (w>0)
                    while (maszyna[w]==maszyna[w-1] || maszyna[w]==maszyna[0])
                        {
                            maszyna[w]= (rand() % 3) +1;
                        }
        }

        t1[0][0]=maszyna[0];
        t1[0][1]=czas[0];
        t2[0][0]=maszyna[1];
        t2[0][1]=czas[1];
        t3[0][0]=maszyna[2];
        t3[0][1]=czas[2];
        /*cout<<"tablice "<< t1[0][0] <<" " << t1[0][1]<<endl;
        cout<<"tablice "<< t2[0][0] <<" " << t2[0][1]<<endl;
        cout<<"tablice "<< t3[0][0] <<" " << t3[0][1]<<endl;*/

        Zadanie pomocnik(t1,t2,t3);
        zadania.push_back(pomocnik);
    }
```

(...)

Comment: Yes, you assign the pointer `operacja1 = t1;` instead of performing a deep copy of the arrays. This also leaks the memory you allocate for `operacja1` before. Instead of the pointer assignment, you should loop through the values of `t1` and assign one by one to the corresponding element of `operacja1`. Same for `operacja2` and `operacja3`.

Comment: Your constructor is leaking memory. This isn't Java. The pointers your passing in and the underlying data they reference isn't being "copied" into your class-member allocations; they're *replacing* them. Further, this class doesn't properly practice the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C++_programming)).

Comment: In C++11 you could use `std::array<int,3>` instead of the `t`s and `operacja`s. Then all this would become easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well for one thing you are effectively creating memory leaks in your constructor

```
Zadanie(int **t1, int **t2, int **t3){
        operacja1= new int*[1];
        operacja1[0]=new int[2];
        operacja2= new int*[1];
        operacja2[0]=new int[2];
        operacja3= new int*[1];
        operacja3[0]=new int[2];
        operacja1=t1;
        operacja2=t2;
        operacja3=t3;
        dlugosc=operacja1[0][1]+operacja2[0][1]+operacja3[0][1];
    }
```

e.g. `operacja1` is first assigned `new int*[1]` then you assign it `t1`

another thing is this

```
int **t1;
t1= new int*[1];
t1[0]=new int[2];
```

t1 is a pointer to a pointer, you allocate space for one pointer i.e. t1[0]
it seems rather superfluous, you could just as might written

```
int *t1 = new int[2];
```

then instead of

```
t1[0][1]=czas[0];
```

you could write

```
t1[1] = czas[0];
```

later you seem to use a vector, I am not sure why you didn't use a vector in the first place instead.

I am not sure this helps with your problem, but is a start.